# running ubuntu of usb making it from current running ubuntu

Tags: usb, 15.10

so I want to create a live-usb so I can take my Ubuntu OS everywhere. but right now I am already running a Ubuntu OS on my pc.I want to take a copy of it so I don’t need to reconfigure everything.
is this possible?

Comment: How big is your PC's Ubuntu partition? Your USB's Ubuntu partition needs to be at least as big to clone it. If your PC is running a Full install of Ubuntu the copy must also be a Full install, not a Live install. There are lots of tutorials out there using dd or Clonezilla.

Comment: i conciderd making it a full install, also the ubuntu partition is around 25gb where my usb is around 32

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I don't see why you couldn't make an ISO file of your system with Clonezilla, then create a live bootable, and persistent USB from that ISO, with PendriveLinux, Unetbootin, or similar applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the one partition you can use dd to clone the internal drive to the USB drive. If you have multiple partitions on the internal drive you can clone only the Ubuntu partition using dd, (or clonezilla), but you will need to install grub.

A bunch of cloning info here: https://askubuntu.com/tags/clonezilla/hot